# Assign a list with a missing value to a Pandas Series in Python

Tags: pandas, boolean, python-2.6, series, missing-data

Something wired when I tried to assign a list with missing value `np.nan` to a `Pandas` `Series`
Below are the codes to reproduce the fact.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
S = pd.Series(0, index = list('ABCDE'))
>>> S
A    0
B    0
C    0
D    0
E    0
dtype: int64

ind = [True, False, True, False, True]
x = [1, np.nan, 2]

>>> S[ind]
A    0
C    0
E    0
dtype: int64
```

Assign x to S[ind]

```
S[ind] = x
```

Something wired in `S`

```
>>> S
A     1
B     0
C     2
D     0
E   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I am expecting `S` to be

```
>>> S
A     1
B     0
C     NaN
D     0
E     2
dtype: float64
```

Anyone can give an explanation for this?

Comment: I get the expected output, I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.10, NumPy 1.10.1, and Pandas 0.17.1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Python 2.6.6, NumPy 1.9.2 and Pandas 0.16.0. I should list the version of both modules.

Comment: Maybe updating is a good idea then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
S[S[ind].index] = x
```

or

```
S[S.index[ind]] = x
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am curious why it happens.